# Please suggest me some solutions for building a project using color uml

Tags: colors, uml

I'm planning a web project but i don`t know where to start.
my colleagues suggested I use color uml and gave me a book
"Java Modeling in Color with UML"

Can you suggest some resource available to learn color uml and how to use it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter Code wrote a book on this color subject about 10 years ago.

I don't remember the name of the book :-(

Comment: The name of the book is "Java Modeling in Color with UML" :)